# Get the TextBlock in a ListView in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone

I am using Windows 8.1. I have a ListView which populates using ItemsSource property.
And in my ListView.ItemTempalte, it has a TextBox.

```
<ListView
      ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Group.Property1}" 
                      Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

My question is how can I get the last item text box in my C# code? The code behind for the xaml page that I show above? For example, I have 10 items in my CollectionGroups, my list view should have 10 text box. How can I get the 10th Text box of the list view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to assign names to your markup:

```
<ListView
  ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}" x:Name="lvGroupData">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Group.Property1}" 
                  Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" x:Name="tbProperty1" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then you need a VisualTreeHelper method (this is the standard way, you will find methods that are more or less like this one all over the web):

```
public T FindElementByName<T>(DependencyObject element, string sChildName) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    T childElement = null;
    var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
    for (int i = 0; i < nChildCount; i++)
    {
        FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;

        if (child == null)
            continue;

        if (child is T && child.Name.Equals(sChildName))
        {
            childElement = (T)child;
            break;
        }

        childElement = FindElementByName<T>(child, sChildName);

        if (childElement != null)
            break;
    }
    return childElement;
}
```

Now you can access the element you need:

```
this.UpdateLayout(); 
// Get the last item here
var lvItem = this.lvGroupData.Items[this.lvGroupData.Items.Count - 1];
var container = this.lvGroupData.ContainerFromItem(lvItem);
// NPE safety, deny first
if (container == null)
    return;
var textboxProperty1 = FindElementByName<TextBox>(container, "tbProperty1");
// And again deny if we got null
if (textboxProperty1 == null)
    return;
/*
  Start doing your stuff here.
*/
```